# Compersing a new file in a backup folder and move it to another folder

Tags: powershell, shell, scripting

On a Windows 10 machine, I have a backup folder where I have daily `db.bak` files coming from an automated SQL server backup job.

I am trying to figure out a way to create a duplicate zip file for every new `.bak` file that comes to the backup folder and move that zip file to a new location without deleting the original `.bak` file.

I am thinking this is possible with PowerShell, but have not figured out a way to do this as an automated process.

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need to do:

```
Compress-Archive -Path "D:\Test.bak" -DestinationPath "F:\Backup\Test.zip"
```